# Git reset --soft HEAD~40 is throwing error

Tags: git

I want to squash all the commits on a branch. (around 100 commits).
I ran the command.

```
git reset --soft HEAD~40
```

But it is throwing the error,

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~40': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
>
> Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
> 'git  [...] -- [...]'

Not sure why is this happening.

Comment: Does your current branch has more than 50 commits?

Comment: @aydinugur: changed the number in the heading but your question ist still valid.

Comment: what is the output of `git log --graph --oneline | head -n 41`>?

Comment: I did a reset once, after which i dint check for the number of commits. My bad. Will close the issue.

Comment: Does using `git log` to locate the commit you want to reset back to and then `git reset --soft <hash to reset back to>` also throw an error?